# How to search archived items in Trello?

Tags: trello

Is there currently a way to search the cards that have been archived in Trello?

The header menu search seems to be limited to live items at the moment.

Comment: If you need this feature please vote here! https://trello.com/c/7dPc8W3B Thanks.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I think this is live (since 2012/06/28) just search after "is:archived" and whatever term you look for.

Source: https://trello.com/card/better-search/4d5ea62fd76aa1136000000c/1016

Answer (score 5):

Sort of.

When viewing a board, click on the "View Archive..." button near the top-right of the screen. This allows you to view either Cards or Lists.

At the bottom is a "Load More Cards" link, for if you have more archived cards than first shown.

Then use your browser's Find feature, to highlight cards whose names contain the text you were looking for.

I this is the best that's possible at the moment.

Comment: Ok, that's pretty much what I thought... someone on my team was hoping that Trello could function as sort of 'group memory', which is not so easy if you can't search archived items.

Comment: Can you clarify the location of this "view archive" button. I do not see it on my board. I'm new, so I can't post images. See here for a screenshot: https://trello.com/card/board/view-archive/4e9c2b0d46e907814302050c/4e9c2b2346e9078143020a14

Comment: @Rhiannon - It's a button on the right-hand side under you Members list

Comment: Currently, the option is available under `Options->Archived Items` on the right panel.

Answer (score 1):

Tips: A quick way to find an archived card's number is to hover over it, and look at the end of the link in your browser's status bar.

Find Archived cards here: ‘Options’ on the right panel -> Archived items -> see 'Archived Cards' list, point mouse to a card, check the URL on the bottom. For example, if you see https://trello.com/card/mentioning-cards-by...099/46 then you know the card number is 46.

So, you don’t have to open an archived card to actually see its number (ones you open and then close it, you have to go to the 'Options' again.

Source: https://trello.com/card/mentioning-cards-by-number-e-g-46-creates-hyperlinks/4f84a60f0cbdcb7e7d40e099/46